# Translation constraints throw array to string conversion

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to translate my own constraint messages defined in validation.yml. I have something like this:

```
Adviser\WebServicesBundle\Entity\Messages:
    problem:
            - Type:
                type: string
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Length:
                min: 2
                max: 1000
                minMessage: { message: 'author' }
```

I need to translate the tag minMessage, it works fine if I put a text directly. I have a file named validators.es.yml inside the directory "Resources/translation" where is located the translation message:

```
author: "Message too short"
```

I also have proved using a xlf format adding the following content overriding the file validators.es.xlf:

```
<trans-unit id="81">
            <source>author</source>
            <target>Message too short</target>
</trans-unit>
```

I get the same error in both cases, "**Array to string conversion**" when I submit the form to force the message. This is the piece of code which throws the exception:

```
     $domain = 'messages';
    }
    $id = (string) $id;
    $catalogue = $this->getCatalogue($locale);
    $locale = $catalogue->getLocale();
    while (!$catalogue->defines($id, $domain)) {
```

I have followed carefully this documentation with no success http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages

I am currently working with symfony 2.7 and any other translations work fine throughout the whole project. I just have this problem with own constraint messages, I don't understand why the validation.yml file can't get the defined messages. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your translation file is different from what is in symfony documentation:

```
<class name="AppBundle\Entity\Author">
    <property name="name">
        <constraint name="NotBlank">
            <option name="message">author.name.not_blank</option>
        </constraint>
    </property>
</class>
```

So it's simply not enough to just provide translation as usual for validation messages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's the validation file in xml, I can't see your point, what do you exactly mean?. I'm using yaml format as the documentation says becasue I'm used to it and seems clearer to me. I think the format shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Could you show a piece of content from your yml file then?

Comment: There are two yml files validation.yml and validators.es.yml. I have put the content of both in my first comment.